# Laravel modifying multiple rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array of `$ids`.

I'd like to essentially say:

```
foreach($ids as $id):

  $user = User::find(1);
  $user->life_expectancy -= 1;
  $user->save();

endforeach;
```

Except I have thousands of ids in the array, and I'd much rather do something like:

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(array('life_expectancy' => --1));
```

To just get it done in a single query. But that isn't going to work... is there another method?

I know I can update multiple users to all have the same `life_expectancy`, but I'd like it to be a modification of the previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this site, http://community.sitepoint.com/t/one-sql-statement-to-subtract-and-update-a-field-value/4673 if you decide to use a raw query, but looking on [laravel's docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates) I think you can just do this,

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', $ids)->decrement('life_expectancy');
```

Comment: Hey, don't go worrying just yet, There may be a way for this still. decrement can optionally take in an extra param for how much to decrement. so `->decrement('life_expectancy', 2)` decrements by 2. Worst case scenario is maybe having to do separate queries for the ones that will increment by one, and one for ones that increment for 2, three, and so on. Essentially separate queries for each different increment.

Comment: @Djave did my comment work for you? If so allow me to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
App\User::whereIn('id',[1,2])->decrement('life_expectancy');
```

If you need -2 use next string:

```
App\User::whereIn('id',[1,2])->decrement('life_expectancy',2);
```